# Multiple, possibly infinite, inputs in Python

Tags: python

Python newbie here.

I need to write a program that asks the user to:

1. enter at least three names (but can also be more) (the names of the accompanying cvs files)
2. a) if the name has already been entered or

   b) the cvs file with that name does not exist
   => new name must be entered (both errors must generate a print message requesting the user to enter a new name)

The fun part: only sequence, selection (If…(then); elif; Switch) and iteration (For...next/For...in; Repeat...until/While True...(condition)/Do...while; While...), call by object/reference, booleans, loops can be used. No build-in Python functions are allowed.

For 2a maybe a loop with a boolean? But how would that be structured for possibly infinite names?

For 2b I found something like this in my course notes, but I don't know how to adapt it to my situation

```
from os import path

name = "myfile"
if not path.exists(name + '.csv'):
print("File does not exist.".format(name=name)
```

Comment: There's only one python builtin that could really be of any use here and that's `input` so, good luck avoiding that. Indeed, I would struggle with this task if that's an accurate statement of the problem

Comment: You should read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)